# How can I find angle between two vectors?

Tags: c++, c, math, geometry

I want to know is polygon convex. For that I need know all angles. If all angles are smaller than 180 degrees then it's convex. If one of angles is bigger than 180 then it's not convex. But how can I find angle?

Comment: Have you tried asking it?

Comment: This question, as far as I can see, has nothing to do with C++. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Even if that was noob, it was meant to be asked on SE Maths.

Comment: You might start here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polygon.html

Answer (score 2):

[You've goofed up even before you've started.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

**In order to find out if a polygon is convex**, calculate the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of each adjacent pair of sides going in order clockwise around the polygon. Stop at the first negative Z component, since you now know that the polygon is concave.